Some kind of generalized Leibniz Rule
I want to compute a modified version of the following: Defining $ \partial_i := \frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}$
we can write
$$ \partial_{a_1} \cdots \partial_{a_n} \: q_{a_1} \cdots q_{a_n} = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \prod_{i=1}^n \delta_{a_i a_{\sigma(i)}} $$
Now if I sum over all $ \{a_i\}_{i=1}^n $ where every index ranges from 1 to N, then
$$ \sum_{\{a\}}  \prod_{i=1}^n \delta_{a_i a_{\sigma(i)}} = Z(S_n; N, \dots , N) $$
where $Z(S_n)$ is the cycle index polynomial of the symmetric group $S_n$ and every cycle of any length will provide a factor of $N$, since every cycle traces the identiy matrix. This case is straightforward because its just a permutation on the set of indices i.e. a bijection of them on themselves. Now my problem is the computation of a modified case like
$$ (\prod_{j=1}^n\partial_{a_j}) \: (q_{a_1}^2 \prod_{i=3}^n q_{a_i}) $$
as you can see the index $a_1$ "appears twice" in the sense that if I go through with the derivatives it would be like a mapping $$ \{a_1,\dots,a_n\} \to \{a_1, a_1, a_3,\dots, a_n\} $$ but this is not a bijection and hence no permuation. Do you guys know how to give a closed form for this case and even cases where more than one $q_{a_i}$ appears quadratically?

In the modified expression, we're still taking the partial wrt $q_2$ but the product expression has no $q_2$ multiplicands, so the answer is $0$, no?

I dont think so, since we have variable indices that take value between 1 and k. There will be cases in the sum where they do not vanish.
